# How to type the char "<" or ">" in JuiceSSH on android

Tags: android, ssh, terminal, keyboard

I want to use JuiceSSH on my android, but
I do not find the sign "<" or ">" in the keyboard.

For example, I can't write the command:

echo hello > file1

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the other keys the "<" and ">" are set in the bottom line near by the space bar